# Efficiency in multiple instances of === parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a more efficient way to display this:

```
$(this).text() === "something" || $(this).text() === "somethingelse"
```

as something like this:

```
$(this).text() === ("something" || "something else")
```

---

Clarity's sake: I'm not suggesting it should be exactly as I displayed. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do what I'm suggesting. So, I'm not repeating the same command. I'm just trying to compare certain text, for instance.

Comment: The second version is not valid syntax for what you want to achieve so you don't really have much of a choice :) The best thing you can do would be to cache the jQuery object in a variable so you don't keep creating new instances of jQuery

Comment: Obviously... I'm just wondering if there is an efficient way to not have to duplicate the same command over and over again when I'm only trying to compare text, for instance.

Comment: Well, it's valid syntax, but the semantics are very different from what you'd likely want.

Comment: @ScottSauyet true, I clarified my point.

Comment: Obviously you can store the result of a calculation in a variable, then do multiple comparisons on that variable...

Comment: A `switch` statement could potentially be a better choice.

Comment: `$(this).text()` can be saved in a variable though! in some cases with more comparisons `['one','two`,'three`].indexOf(text) !== -1` can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods which can achieve the desire result

Method 1 - using [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
var myList = ["something", "somethingElse"];
if (myList.indexOf($(this).text()) !== -1) {
    //ok
} else {
    //nok
}
```

Method 2 - using [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
//This yields to false
$.inArray( 5 + 5, [ "8", "9", "10", 10 + "" ] );
//This yields to true
$.inArray( 5 + 5, [ "8", "9", "10", 10 ] );
```

The reason this happens is because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false

Method 3 - using [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.includes(2); // true 
a.includes(4); // false
```

Method 4 - [switches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```
switch (expression) {
  case value1:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches value1
    [break;]
  case value2:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches value2
    [break;]
    default:
    //Statements executed when none of the values match the value of the expression
    [break;]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create array of options and check if your value is in that array.

```
["something", "something else"].indexOf($(this).text()) != -1
```

With ES7 you can use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
["something", "something else"].includes($(this).text())
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.includes` is actually an ES7 method.

Comment: And with jQuery: [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: @undefined so ECMAScript 2016 is ES7?

Comment: Well, the ECMAScript 2016 is the 7th edition of the standard so we can call it ES7.